# Windows Failover Cluster - High Availability

Tags: failovercluster

I set up a Windows Failover Cluster on WS2012.
Is there a way to replicate the cluster on another server to have a sort of high availability of the cluster itself?

My concern is about the scenario when the machine hosting the cluster crashes or need to reboot. The cluster goes off, of course, and with it, all roles (for example SQL Server Always ON)

Comment: Why would you need to replicate the cluster to `another server`? Do you only have one server in your cluster?

Comment: I have two hosts (ESXi), on each of them I have a SQL server VM, and a Always On High Availability group, which uses Windows Failover Cluster service. The service is on a VM in one of the two hosts. If that host fails, the cluster goes down, even if the second SQL server (on second host) is still on.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of why you'd need to "replicate" the cluster to the other server. If you have two ESXi hosts and each of those has a WSFC node, how would the cluster go off line if a host failed?

Comment: I wrote: "The service is on a VM in one of the two hosts" WSFC is running only on one of the two ESXi hosts. That's basically my concern, if that ESXi host goes off, the WSFC goes off as well, since there is no replication of WSFC on seconf host.

Comment: So what does the second SQL VM do then? Is it not part of the Always On High Availability Group? Does your WSFC only have a single node?

Comment: Here's my configuration: ESXi 1: [WSFC VM] + [SQL (HA) VM] + [WEB VM] ; ESXi 2: [SQL1 (HA)] + [WEB1]. WSFC has 4 nodes (SQL + SQL1 + WEB + WEB1)

Comment: If your failover cluster has 4 nodes (SQL, SQL1, WEB, WEB1) what does [WSFC VM] do then?

Comment: WSFC VM is the domain controller, where DNS records for SQL Always on (Availability group listener) are stored. I have a secondary domain controller with DNS on ESXi 2. Here's the crucial questions (2): question1: what happens if ESXi goes down completely? Who's telling SQL1 to do a failover and become principal? question2: is secondary domain controller and secondary DNS enough to maintain accessibility to DNS entries? Thanks

Comment: There's way too many issues with your questions and your understanding of the technologies involved for me to answer, in comments or otherwise, so I'm not even going to try. Please read any/all documentation for WSFC, vSphere and AD/DNS. If you still have *specific* questions about these things, come back and ask them, but using the right terms (WSFC is *not* AD/DNS), providing relevant configurations and details, and asking questions that make sense will yield better results.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the redundancy using hyper-v replication. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134172.aspx

Basically you would setup 2 clusters and a replica broker on each cluster. You could then replicate your VMs from one cluster to another and failover if required.

One thing to note certain applications aren't supported such as Sql and exchange. The correct method is to use the applications own high availability methods. Such as database availability groups for exchange and always on for sql.

Edit:

Vmware has a similar product https://www.vmware.com/uk/products/vsphere/features/replication

The note about unsuitable products still applies as far as I know.

Comment: You answer correctly to my question, so I'll give a +1. Unfortunately my hypervisor is ESXI (free), this complicates things. Maybe I'll switch to hyper-v bare metal in the future

Comment: Added a link for vmware. Sorry should of asked what hypervisor